# Displaying Records in Multiple Columns Using PHP

Tags: php

I'm trying to display two (2) columns instead of my current one (1) column.

My example here:
http://freeskateboardsticker.com/news/authors.php

I have rewritten the script many times, but I cannot seem to get the rows and columns to display correctly and still keep the pagination intact.

Below is my script:

```
<?php include_once(realpath("templates/top.php")); ?>
<?php include_once(realpath("templates/$templates/mid1.php")); ?>

<?php
$page = @$_GET["page"];
$start = @$_GET["start"];

if (!is_numeric($page) || $page < 1)
    $page = 1;

if ($page == 1)
    $start = 0;
else
    $start = ($page * $authorsPerPage) - $authorsPerPage;

$aResult = mysql_query("select pk_alId, alEmail, alFName, alLName, alBio, alDateJoined from tbl_AdminLogins order by alFName, alLName limit $start, $authorsPerPage");
$numRows = mysql_num_rows(mysql_query("select pk_alId from tbl_AdminLogins order by alFName, alLName"));

if ($numRows > 0) {
    ?>
    <!-- Start Authors -->
    <div align="center">
        <center>
            <TABLE WIDTH="86%" BORDER="0" CELLSPACING="0" CELLPADDING="0"> 
                <TR> 
                    <TD WIDTH="100%" HEIGHT="20" COLSPAN="2" ALIGN="right" class="BodyText" VALIGN="top"><FONT COLOR="#0B75AF"> <?PHP
    if ($page > 1)
        $nav .= "<a href='authors.php?page=" . ($page - 1) . "'><span class='Link1'><u>&#171; Prev</u></span></a> | ";
    for ($i = 1; $i <= ceil($numRows / $authorsPerPage); $i++)
        if ($i == $page)
            $nav .= "<a href='authors.php?page=$i'><span class='Link4'><b>$i</b></span></a> | ";
        else
            $nav .= "<a href='authors.php?page=$i'><span class='Link1'>$i</span></a> | ";

    if (($start + $authorsPerPage) < $numRows && $numRows > 0)
        $nav .= "<a href='authors.php?page=" . ($page + 1) . "'><span class='Link1'><u>Next &#187;</u></span></a>";

    if (substr(strrev($nav), 0, 2) == " |")
        $nav = substr($nav, 0, strlen($nav) - 2);
    echo $nav . "<br>&nbsp;";
    ?></FONT>
                    </TD> 
                </TR> 
            </TABLE>
    <?php while ($aRow = mysql_fetch_array($aResult)) { ?>
                <div align="center"><center>
                        <TABLE WIDTH="720" CELLSPACING="0" CELLPADDING="0" BORDER="0"> 
                            <TR> 
                                <TD WIDTH="185"> <?php if ($showAuthorImages) { ?><img src="imageview.php?what=getAuthorPic&authorId=<?php echo $aRow["pk_alId"]; ?>">&nbsp;<?php } ?></TD> 
                                <TD WIDTH="5" VALIGN="top"> </TD> 
                                <TD WIDTH="530" VALIGN="MIDDLE"><SPAN CLASS="BodyHeading1"><?PHP echo $aRow["alFName"]; ?></SPAN>
                                    <BR><span class="Text1"><?php echo $aRow["alBio"]; ?></span><br></TD> 
                            </TR> 
                            <TR> 
                                <TD COLSPAN="3">  </TD> 
                            </TR> 
                        </TABLE>
                    </center></div>
    <?php } ?>
            <div align="center">
                <center>
                    <table width="96%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                        <tr>
                            <td width="100%" height="20" colspan="2" align="right" valign="top">
                                <SPAN CLASS="Text4"><?php echo $nav . "<br>&nbsp;"; ?></SPAN>
                                <br>&nbsp;
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </center>
            </div>
            <!-- End Authors -->
            <?php
        } else {
            // No authors found in the database
            ?>
            <!-- StartAuthors -->
            <div align="center">
                <center>
                    <table width="96%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                        <tr>
                            <td width="100%" colspan="2" bgcolor="#FFFFFF" height="21">
                                <span class="BodyHeading">
                                    <br>No Authors Found
                                </span>
                                <span class="Text1">
                                    <br><br>
                                    No authors were found in the database. Please use
                                    the link below to return to our home page.
                                    <br><br>
                                </span>
                                <a href="index.php">Return Home</a>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </center>
            </div>
            <!-- End Authors -->
            <?php
        }
        ?>
```

Comment: Can you format your code? It is painful to read

Answer (score 0):

1. Do not use font tag, it is deprecated
2. br /> not br>
3. If you are writing  then write all other tags also in lower case
4. Use some MySQLi library (PDO etc)
5. Do not put center and div with align center tag into while cycle
6. Build table rows in while cycle, not one table per one author (table beginning before while, table ending after while cycle, inside while leave onl tr/td generation)

Comment: Ok.  I appreciate that and I made the changes, but this does not allow me to make two coloumns.

Comment: Everytime I use your suggestion, its blows the scripting.  Why?  Not sure.

Comment: Okay, I've got the two columns working, but the data is repeating itself for both columns.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Move your loop inside the table, to create a new row per iteration, not a new table:

```
<div align="center">
    <center>
        <TABLE WIDTH="720" CELLSPACING="0" CELLPADDING="0" BORDER="0"> 
            <?php while ($aRow = mysql_fetch_array($aResult)) { ?>
                <TR> 
                    <TD WIDTH="185"> <?php if ($showAuthorImages) { ?><img src="imageview.php?what=getAuthorPic&authorId=<?php echo $aRow["pk_alId"]; ?>">&nbsp;<?php } ?></TD> 
                    <TD WIDTH="5" VALIGN="top"> </TD> 
                    <TD WIDTH="530" VALIGN="MIDDLE"><SPAN CLASS="BodyHeading1"><?PHP echo $aRow["alFName"]; ?></SPAN>
                        <BR><span class="Text1"><?php echo $aRow["alBio"]; ?></span><br></TD> 
                </TR> 
                <TR> 
                    <TD COLSPAN="3">  </TD> 
                </TR> 
            <?php } ?>
        </TABLE>
    </center>
</div>
```

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '}' in /home/freeskat/public_html/news/authors.php on line 76

Comment: Nevermind, found that error, however I still can't put in two coloumns and I'm getting an error on the pagnation now.  Warning: Division by zero in /home/freeskat/public_html/news/authors.php on line 30

Comment: I've been looking at this way too long, I guess.

Comment: Try to temporary remove pagination code and see if the data does  appear in 2 columns. Your goal is to put it into a single table, but into different `<td>` cells. After you make 2 columns, put pagination code back and fix that.

Comment: Like this?   $cols=3;
 echo "<table>";
 do{
  echo "<td>";
  for($i=1;$i<=$cols;$i++){

Comment: Everything is going as planned, except for the two coloumns.

Comment: I've never used jsfiddle before.  Looks interesting.  The HTML output is here.  http://freeskateboardsticker.com/news/authors.php

Comment: Can you please take a look and see if you can find why I'm only showing one column?  Thanks.

Comment: Okay, I've got the two columns working, but the data is repeating itself for both columns.  Any ideas?